# Equivalence of $0$-dependent and indenpendent

Tags: probability-theory, time-series

A series of random variables $\{X_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$, $X_i: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is called $0$-independent if for every $t\in\mathbb{Z}$,

$(\cdots,X_{t-1},X_t)$ and $(X_{t+1},\cdots)$ are independent.

The same series is called independent if for arbitrary subset $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$,

$(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is independent.

independent $\implies$ $0$-independent is straightforward.

How about the other direction? 
Should I use marginal distirbution $\mathbb{P}(X_t\in B_t, X_{t+1}\in \Omega,\cdots) = \mathbb{P}(X_t\in B_t)$?

Comment: Please modify the definition of 0-independence, the current version is absurd. / "The other direction" indeed holds. / What happened to your previous question on the same topic?

Comment: @Did Which question do you refer to? I don't remember I have  asked the same question before.

Comment: A very similar question was asked quite recently.

Comment: @Did The questions asked recently are about product topology. I cannot connect them with independence.